# Which of the following relations are true?Here $[x]$ denotes the greatest integer less then or equal to $x$ (as in option b) symbol

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Which of the following relations are true?

$1)$ $(-1)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}} = (-1)^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}$

$2)$ $(-1)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}} = (-1)^{[\frac{n}{2}]}$

$3)$ $(-1)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}} = (-1)^{n^2}$

Here $[x]$  denotes  the  greatest  integer  less then or equal to $x$ (as in
 option b) symbol

My attempts :   if  I take  $n=0$  then all option $1,2,3$ are  True

Any other   logics?

Comment: You should also test with $n=1$, and see what happens to $1)$ and $3)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $n=4k+1$ then last one is not true.

Also $$(-1)^{{n(n+1)\over 2}} = (-1)^{{n(n-1)\over 2}+n}=(-1)^{{n(n-1)\over 2}}(-1)^n$$

so for $n$ is odd it is not true.

---

So, only the second can be always true:

If $n=2k$ then
$$(-1)^{k(2k-1)} = (-1)^k = (-1)^{[\frac{n}{2}]}$$
If $n=2k+1$ then
$$(-1)^{(2k+1)k} = (-1)^k = (-1)^{[\frac{n}{2}]}$$